# AngularJS different templateURL each iteration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My HTML

```
<load ng-repeat="item in widget" type="{{item.type}}" ></load>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('load', function() {      
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'templates/label.html',
        link:function(scope,elem,att){
         } 
    };

});
```

I want use attribute type in templateUrl. Each element has other type and I want use different templates.

I create new element load, no load via ng-include etc. because I need replace elements with repeat.

Comment: Have you tried doing `'templates/label-'+{{type}}+'.html'` or something like that? And then just pass in the `type` via the `scope` binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can not dynamically set a template url but you can set and use a ng-include, try this:

```
replace: true,   
restrict: 'E',
template: '<div ng-include="includeUrl"></div>',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.includeUrl = 'templates/label-' + attrs.type + '.html';
}
```

Comment: you can if you use `template:function(){}` or `templateUrl:function(){}`

Comment: @user3739239 Yes I can use ng-include with template, but template content will be added to this div, I wont this.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I can use function in templateUrl but attribute return in this function plain text.